# issue with DataTemplate on WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a `DataTemplate` that is defined in App.xaml and is used in 2 places (`ItemControls`).

It works perfectly for both except for color of the text.

I assumed that if i define a brush as a `StaticResource` at those 2 places with different value it would work, as it will move up thru the visual tree trying to find the brush resource. But as `DataTemplate` is defined in `App.xaml` it looks for the brush only in App resources, not in the place where the `DataTemplate` is used.

Can i somehow reuse the `DataTemplate` in 2 places with custom brushes (without any global brush in App.xaml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you a way but I don't know if it will be the most optimum solution for your problem.

What you can do is move your data template to user control and define your brush inside user control resources, in this way you can reuse your control with the same brush. I hope it helps.

Comment: I want to use template at 2 differnt places(pages). And it should have different color brush.

Comment: then define a dependency property in your control and set the color at the two different places.

Comment: In what control ? I'm trying to use 1 DataTemplate in 2 ItemsControl (at 2 different pages)

Comment: That is what I am suggesting. Convert your data template into a usercontrol with the colorBrush as a dependency property and use the usercontrol where you have a requirement